# Writing a multiplayer game in Django

Tags: python, database, django, game-engine

I'm planning to write a multiplayer card game in Django. There may be several concurrent games. I already have a Python CardGame class that contains the engine for the game, and for every game that is created I will need one instance of this class, to be open until the game is closed. This object will basically keep the state of the game, and any actions executed by users will be run on this object.

**My question is**:
in Django, how do you create an object that can store the state of the game and listen for commands from the Django views, without using a database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look into serializing your data and store it in a key-value store like [redis](http://www.redis.io/) for example (which is superfast).

Comment: indeed, however @Herman I can't work out why you wouldn't want to use a db - this will give you persistance, and if you go parallel, will handle locking for you.

Comment: @BiggAI: my main reason is speed - I'm not sure that storing and retrieving serialized objects (around 1000 at a time if I have 10,000 users) from a DB will be fast enough. I also have no interest in the exact details of every game, only the outcome.